# Remember "Radio" value when submitting form to self on php page?

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

On a text input, this is how you would "remember" the value the user entered if the form gets submitted to itself, for say a picture upload tool which requires that, so the user wont have to type everything into the form again after uploading a picture.

```
   <input type="text" id="text" name="text" value="<?php echo @$_POST['text'];?>">
```

but how is this done when it comes to radios?

I would prefer not to create the actual radio with php, I would prefer another solution. But in the end I would go with the easiest! Javascript is also okay to use here!

Thanks

Comment: What's with the @ before $_POST? That only works on functions, and should rarely be used.

Comment: it's so that there is no errors given if it's not set... just safer for the users, I think... How would you do it?

Comment: That doesn't work on variables like that, does it? It's for functions.

Comment: @ceejayoz The @ will suppress a notice which will occur if the $_POST doesn't have a value for the 'text' key.
Using it for a variable is less dangerous than it for functions.

Comment: If it works for variables, I just learned something new. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<input type="radio" id="radio_button_1" name="radio_button" value="1"<?php if($_POST['radio_button'] == 1) { print ' checked="checked"'; } ?> />
<input type="radio" id="radio_button_2" name="radio_button" value="2"<?php if($_POST['radio_button'] == 2) { print ' checked="checked"'; } ?> />
```

Comment: Yep, you're right. missed the ""'s, You beat me to it anyway, +1

Answer (score 0):

To short further, you can write this statement as:

```
<input type="radio" id="radio_button_2" name="radio_button" value="2" <?=isset($_POST['radio_button']) ? "checked":"" ?> />
```

Answer (score 0):

I arrived here via Google and the acccepted answer is missing the `if(isset($_POST['radio_button']))` check first, which could be handy in some cases.

```
<input type="radio" id="radio_button_1" name="radio_button" value="1"<?php if(isset($_POST['radio_button']) && $_POST['radio_button'] == 1) { echo ' checked="checked"'; } ?> />
<input type="radio" id="radio_button_2" name="radio_button" value="2"<?php if(isset($_POST['radio_button']) && $_POST['radio_button'] == 2) { echo ' checked="checked"'; } ?> />
```